# CakeEmail not working in add function

Tags: email, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I'm trying out CakeEmail and I am having a problem.
I added the code into my add function, similar to the blog tutorial's add function, but when I add an item it says undefined variable.  If I remove the email code, it works, if I leave it in and refresh the page the item shows up but no email.

Here is the code from the function:

```
public function add()
    {
        $this->set('isAddValid', false);
        $this->set('addValidationErrors', false);

        if ($this->request->is('post'))
        {
            // If the save is successful, close the dialog and display the success message
            // Else, set the error flags.
            if ($this->LocalClock->save($this->request->data))
            {
                $this->set('localClocks', $this->request->data);
                $this->LocalClock->save($localClocks);
                $this->set('isAddValid', true);
                $this->set('addValidationErrors', false);

                $email = new CakeEmail('smtp');
                $email->from(array('me@example.com' => 'Local Clocks'));
                $email->to('you@example.com');
                $email->subject('New Local Clock Added');
                $email->send('A new local clock has been added.');
                CakeEmail::deliver('you@example.com', 'New local Clock', 'New Local Clock Added',
                    array('from' => 'localhost@localhost'));
            }
        }
```

Here is the email.php file in the config folder (i just copied an pasted it from the default file they had in there):

```
class EmailConfig {
    public $default = array(
        'transport' => 'Mail',
        'from' => 'you@localhost',
        //'charset' => 'utf-8',
        //'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
    );

    public $smtp = array(
        'transport' => 'Smtp',
        'from' => array('site@localhost' => 'My Site'),
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'port' => 25,
        'timeout' => 30,
        'username' => 'user',
        'password' => 'secret',
        'client' => null,
        'log' => false,
        //'charset' => 'utf-8',
        //'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
    );

    public $fast = array(
        'from' => 'you@localhost',
        'sender' => null,
        'to' => null,
        'cc' => null,
        'bcc' => null,
        'replyTo' => null,
        'readReceipt' => null,
        'returnPath' => null,
        'messageId' => true,
        'subject' => null,
        'message' => null,
        'headers' => null,
        'viewRender' => null,
        'template' => false,
        'layout' => false,
        'viewVars' => null,
        'attachments' => null,
        'emailFormat' => null,
        'transport' => 'Smtp',
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'port' => 25,
        'timeout' => 30,
        'username' => 'user',
        'password' => 'secret',
        'client' => null,
        'log' => true,
        //'charset' => 'utf-8',
        //'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
    );
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: I get the Notice (8): Undefined variable: localClocks,
The weird thing is the line it specifies having the error is before any email code.

Comment: $this->Email->_debug = true; put in add method and ...see did u getting error.

Comment: Configure::write('debug', 2); also put and see

Comment: I don't get any output from those two commands. I tried using debug($email) as well but that didn't output anything either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the answer required me to add another setting to the email.php file.

I created a gmail account so I can use the email feature.

The code is pretty simple:

```
public $gmail = array(
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => 465,
        'username' => 'account@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'password',
        'transport' => 'Smtp',
        'timeout' => 1
    );
```

And in the add() function:

```
$email = new CakeEmail('gmail');
```

Answer (score 3):

You're problem is exactly what the error says - "Undefined variable: localClocks".

```
$this->set('localClocks', $this->request->data);
$this->LocalClock->save($localClocks);
```

This does NOT set a variable $localClocks - it passes data to a variable, which WILL be accessible from the View (but is not accessible in the controller).

Change to this, and you should be fine (or at least get past this problem):

```
$this->LocalClock->save($this->request->data);
```

Or, if you really want to break it into 2 lines:

```
$localClocks = $this->request->data;
$this->LocalClock->save($localClocks);
```

You can still "set" the variable for use in the View if you'd like, but again - **using $this->set does NOT make a variable accessible from the Controller**.

Comment: Thanks for the catch. I actually removed that line of code because I didn't need it.  I'm not sure why I put that there because it already saves the data. As for the email, it still doesn't send anything. I just get a blank screen.

Comment: probably a good idea to do some debugging to check if you're actually getting into the if block, and wrap an if() around the actual sending of the email as well.

Comment: I think my problem is that I don't actually have an email client set up.  I will keep trying though, thanks.